# Can the limit definition of continuity be considered proof?

Tags: calculus, continuity

So I just started to learn about continuity and the Limit-Definiton for continuity of a function $f$ with domain $D$, i.e:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = f(x_0)\text{ (for all sequences $(x_n)\to x_0$ with }x_n \in D)$$

as well as the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition:
$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in D: |x_0 -x| < \delta \implies |f(x_0) - f(x)| < \epsilon$$
To me the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition seems kind of pointless right now - at least for simple functions.

For example, I see a lot of videos on youtube in which functions like e.g. $\sin(x)$ are proven to be continuous using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method, but wouldn't it be much simpler to just use the limit definition of continuity to say:

$$\forall (x_n)\to x_0\text{ with }x_n \in D: \lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(x_n) = \sin(x_0)$$

There is probably a reason why I do not see this anywhere, although I do not immediately see what is wrong with that approach. If anyone could explain this to me, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's always useful to have equivalent definitions. Continuity is fundamentally topological and doesn't need the notion of limits either or distances to be defined, they just happen to coincide in analysis.

Comment: There are two (equivalent) definitions. Usually, you give one as your primary definition, and then you *prove* (a theorem) that the second statement is equivalent. You can define continuity in terms of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ and then *prove* that $f$ is "limit of sequences continuous" if and only if it is continuous (i.e., "$\epsilon$-$\delta$ continuous); or you can define continuity in terms of the sequence definition and then prove that a function is "$\epsilon$-$delta$ continuous" if and only if it is continuous (i.e., "limit of sequences continuous").

Comment: You are missing the condition that the sequence $(x_n)$ must converge to $x_0$ in your first equation.

Comment: "For all subsequences..." No, should be "for all sequences."

Comment: Well, it's kinda hard to actually prove $\sin(x)$ is continuous from the subsequence definition without eventually invoking some manifestation of the $\epsilon-\delta$ idea,  right? Certainly the way I would do it would devolve into checking that if $x_n$ is sufficiently close to $x_0$ then $\sin(x_n)$ is sufficiently close to $\sin(x_0)$...

Comment: Anyway, how are you going to prove the sequential version of continuity? You have to prove it for all sequences that converge to $x_0,$ which is rather a lot, and even defining what it means for $x_n\to x_0$ requires some $\epsilon-N.$ In the end, you are just going to need to say, "When $|x_n-x_0|<\delta,$ $|f(x_n)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon.$" Sequential continuity gains you nothing.